# Uniform Quotient vs Universal Quotient

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

What is a quotient of an affine scheme that is not a universal quotient?  Let's recall some terminology.

Suppose that $k$ is an algebraically closed field and $G$ is a reductive group acting on an affine scheme $X$.  Theorem 1.1 of  [Geometric Invariant Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=dFlv3zn_2-gC&printsec=frontcover&dq=geometric+invariant+theory&hl=en&ei=SpaNTInmIY2MnQfwmdDUCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)  states that the uniform categorical quotient $X//G$ of $X$ exists.

In other words, $X \to X//G$ is universal with respect to $G$-invariant morphisms out of $X$ and this property persists under base change by a *flat* morphism $T \to X//G$.

When $\text{char}(k)=0$, the theorem states that $X \to X//G$ is a universal categorical quotient, so that the universal property persists under base change by an *arbitrary* morphism $T \to X//G$.

What is an example where $X \to X//G$ is not a universal quotient?

I'd be particularly interested in the case where the stabilizers of the action on $X$ are all linearly reductive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example, which is in some sense the simplest one. Suppose that $k$ has characteristic $p > 0$; set $X := \mathop{\rm Spec} k[x,y]$. Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $p$ acting via $(x,y) \mapsto (x, x+y)$. The ring of invariants is $k[u,v] := k[x, y^p - x^{p-1}y]$. Consider the point $\mathop{\rm Spec} k = \mathop{\rm Spec} k[u,v]/(u,v)$ of $X/G = \mathop{\rm Spec} k[u,v]$; the inverse image $Y$ in $X$ is $\mathop{\rm Spec} k[x,y]/(x, y^p)$; it is immediate to check that the action of $G$ on $Y$ is trivial, so $Y/G = Y \neq  \mathop{\rm Spec} k$.

If you want an example with a connected group, embed $G$ into $\mathrm{GL}_n$ and take the induced action.

I don't know any example with linearly reductive stabilizers, and I suspect that they don't exist.

Comment: Angelo's suspicion is right. By thm of Nagata (Ch.IV, Thm. 3.6 in Demazure-Gabriel), in char. $p > 0$ a smooth affine $k$-gp is lin. red. iff its comp. group has order not divisible by $p$ and id. component is torus.  Hence, enough to treat tori and finite gps of order prime to $p$.  The latter is universal for affine $X$ in char. $p$ via averaging. For tori $S$, can restrict to noetherian base change and then by noetherian induction $S$-invariants in coordinate rings upstairs and downstairs are $S[n]$-invariants for sufficiently divisible $n$ coprime to $p$. So reduced back to the first case.

Comment: Brian, this is for the case of actions of linearly reductive stabilizers, but jlk was asking for the case when the *stabilizers* are linearly reductive, and I think this is much harder

Comment: @Angelo: Thanks. Your interpretation is correct: I would particularly like a proof/example in the case where the stabilizers are all linearly reductive, but the group $G$ is not.

Comment: This is somewhat vague: I think that I at some point verified that with a linearly reductive stabiliser you have (at least) a formal version of the Luna slice theorem, in fact the local completion of an Artin stack at a linearly reductive stabiliser is formally equivalent to an action of the stabiliser on something. This I think would reduce the case of an l.r. stabiliser to the case of a linearly reductive action.

Comment: Dear Torsten, of course the approach would be the one you mention. There is a formal slice theorem for group actions with linearly reductive stabilizers, but it is very hard to get consequences from it. This is discussed in a paper of Jarod Alper, On the local quotient structure of Artin stacks <arxiv.org/abs/0904.2050>.

Comment: I should also mention that there are classical examples where the Luna slice theorem fails, even for actions with finite stabilizers in characteristic 0.

Comment: @Angelo: Could you give one of those examples? I am not familiar with them and would like to see one.  I can post this as a new question, if you prefer.

Comment: Consider the action of $\mathrm{PGL}_2$ on the space of unordered 4-tuples of points of $\mathbb P^1$ (a.k.a. $\mathbb P^4$). The generic stabilizer is isomorphic to the product of two cyclic groups of order 2 (the Klein group); but the stabilizer of a point corresponding to a double points and two distinct point of $\mathbb P^1$ is cyclic of order 2. Clearly, this means that you can't have a slice around this point, since the generic stabilizer is not conjugate to a subgroup of the special stabilizer.